# Editing gpg preferences with gpgconf

Tags: configuration, gnupg

It *seems* like gpgconf should be the nice way to edit my `gpg.conf` file. However, even reading the [documentation](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Changing-options.html#Changing-options), I was unable to figure out how to make a simple change. All I wanted to do is to set the default hash algorithm to SHA256. I ended up just adding

```
personal-digest-preferences SHA256
```

to the bottom of `gpg.conf` manually, but how could I have achieved this using gpgconf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [gpgconf documentation](http://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/gpgconf.html#gpgconf) (highlighting added by me):

> The `gpgconf` is a utility to automatically and reasonable safely query and modify configuration files in the `.gnupg` home directory. **It is designed not to be invoked manually by the user**, but automatically by graphical user interfaces (GUI).
>
> [...] **Not all configuration options are available** through `gpgconf`. `gpgconf` provides a generic and abstract method to access the most important configuration options that can feasibly be controlled via such a mechanism.

But let's see what happens if we try to use it anyway:

```
$ echo 'personal-digest-preferences:0:SHA256' | gpgconf --change-options gpg
gpgconf: unknown option personal-digest-preferences
gpgconf: fatal error (exit status 1)
```

Apparently, `personal-digest-preferences` does not belong to this set of "most important configuration options" and you should edit the `gpg.conf` manually as suggested.